# I have a custom post type with taxonomies, it shows all my taxonomies on one page and want to limit 10 taxonomies per page how can I do this?

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type with taxonomies, it shows all my taxonomies on one page and I want to limit 10 taxonomies per page how can I do that?

I'm using the following code, does anyone have suggestions or ideas why it's not working? Thanks in advance!

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
    $post_type = 'brinton';
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );
    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :

    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
    foreach( $terms as $term ) : 
?>

<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term->slug,
            )
        )

    );
    $posts = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $posts->have_posts() ):
?>   

<div class="cp-product-list-w">
    <div class="c-haeding-3">
        <h4><?php echo $term->name; ?></h4>
        <h2 class="c-brinton-cat"><?php echo $term->description; ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cp-product-list-in">
        <div class="c-container">
            <div class="row">  

                <?php while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

                <div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                    <div class="cp-product-list-box brintons-list">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
                        <div class="cp-product-list-box-img">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="brintons-list-d">
                            <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <?php 
                                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                                $product_sku = get_field('brinton_product_sku', $post_id); 
                            ?>
                            <p><?php echo $product_sku; ?></p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: _"and I want to limit 10 taxonomies per page"_ - you mean _posts_ per page, right? The keyword is _pagination_, and how that works in WP, is well documented, so do a bit of reaearch & reading up on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

This line `'posts_per_page' => -1,` means you're going to show them all. Try changing the -1 to 10.